# Codeforces: "B. 8 Queens, Again"

Tags: c, n-queens

The problem is here: [B. 8 Queens, Again!!](https://codeforces.com/gym/100947/problem/B)

I think I'm not getting the worst cases or missing something. My submission failed in **test 2**.

I've just checked rows, columns and diagonals for each input with their next ones.I thought this would be enough. Is there any other case where is can be valid or invalid? I'm not sure my code is all correct though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int t, y[9], x[9], i, j, valid;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        valid = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            scanf(" %c %d", &x[i], &y[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(j = i+1; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if(x[i] == x[j] || y[i] == y[j] || abs(x[i] - x[j]) == abs(y[i]-y[j])) valid = 0;
            }
        }
        (valid) ? printf("Valid\n") : printf("Invalid\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing the coordinates. Your `scanf` may be reading the newline character. I always use `fgets` just to get rid of the newline character at the end of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're `scanf`ing the character of the  coordinates in the input file into an `int`.

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    char row;
    scanf("%1c%1d ", &row, &y[i]);
    x[i] = row - 'A';
}
```

An `int` is probably 4 or 8 bytes.  Since these are local, their contents are undefined until set.  The character goes into the first byte, the remaining bytes are still undefined.  It may work, it may not.  Additionally, this will never work on big-endian machines, since you're storing it in the most-significant byte instead of least-significant.  See: [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Make sure your argument types agree with the `scanf` string.  Possibly, your compiler gave you a warning to the effect of `warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’`; if so, this is what it was trying to tell you.

Comment: For which input does that cause trouble or the program to fail in OPs version but does work for your version? Please provide an example accordingly.

Comment: @Yunnosch It fixes a compile warning, and since `x` is local, it has undefined value.  The `scanf` changes the first byte, but not the rest.  Probably they're zero because it's a freshly launched program, but even so, I'd expect differing behavior on little-endian vs. big-endian architectures.

Comment: You could noticably improve your answer by explaining those things inside the answer and in more detail. Please try to explain how the first case can pass (only test 2 fails according to OP). Only if you can explain that it actually answers the question.